# In Landau & Lifshitz's 'Theory of elasticity' why are scalars $u_{ik}^2$ and $u_{ii}^2$ said to be independent? They vary with the reference system

Tags: energy, tensor-calculus, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, invariants

[image]

Scalars $u_{ik}^2$ and $u_{ii}^2$ depend on the reference system (are not invariants), why are they said to be independent? I have tried to rotate the reference system for a given tensor but $F$ varies with the rotations.

Comment: You haven’t explained why you think they are not invariants. How do you think they transform?

Comment: The 3 principal invariants have a different expression. Further, I have tried substituting numerical values for the same tensor but in 2 different reference frames and the scalar function varies.

Comment: "*The 3 principal invariants have a different expression.*" There are an infinite number of invariant expressions; perhaps you just haven't seen them expressed in this way before. "*I have tried substituting numerical values for the same tensor but in 2 different reference frames and the scalar function varies.*" So please show those details; published literature has a far higher credibility than a claim without valid evidence. I suspect the problem lies with the implementation of "squared sum" and/or "sum of squares."

Comment: Here a numeric example follows: 
let's consider the tensor $u_{ij}$
\begin{array}{l}0.023&-0.015&0.001\\-0.015&0.009&0.008\\0.001&0.008&0.013\end{array}
the strain tensor associated to the principal directions becomes:
\begin{array}{l}0.0332&0&0\\0&0.01558&0\\0&0&-0.00378\end{array}
For the latter tensor: $u_{ii}^2=0.000779$ , $u_{ik}^2=0.00079$ , $u_{ii}^2+u_{ik}^2=0.001558$
For the first tensor: $u_{ii}^2=0.0013593$ , $u_{ik}^2=0.001359$ , $u_{ii}^2+u_{ik}^2=0.0027183$

Comment: $u_{ii}^2$ means $(\sum_i u_{ii})^2$, not $\sum_i (u_{ii})^2$. If you calculate correctly, the expressions are invariant, as fully contracted tensors are guaranteed to be. It’s fine to see how it works with explicit numbers, but I recommend that you learn more abstractly why fully contracted tensors are invariant. Write how the tensor transforms under a general rotation $R_{ij}$ and use the properties of rotation matrices.

Answer (score 2):

The notations $u_{ii}^2$ means what Landau & Lifschitz define it as:  the square of the sum of the diagonal components, not the sum of the squares of the diagonal components.  In other words,
$$
u_{ii}^2 \equiv \left( \sum_i u_{ii} \right)^2 \neq \sum_i u_{ii}^2.
$$
In both of the cases in the example you provide in the comments, this works out to about 0.002025.